# Argument handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple function "arr(n)" that returns a list of numbers up to n:

```
def arr(n):
    return [r for r in range(n)]
```

However, I am given a case where no arguments are passed into the arr(n) function, so just arr(). Which yields this error:

```
TypeError: arr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

I've been unable to look up or come up with a solution to circumvent this problem. Could you lend me a hand?

Comment: what would the the `range` function use if given no `n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function signature `def arr(n)` is telling Python that when that function is called it *must* receive a single [positional argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

If you expect to receive no arguments then a suggestion would be to create a [default argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

```
def arr(n=0):
    return [r for r in range(n)]
```

In the case of `arr()` you will get an empty list (`[]`). Otherwise, for some integer `i`, you will get `[0, 1, ..., i]`.

Comment: Ooh! Worked like a charm! I've never seen that technique before, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is because you defined a function which needs the value `n`

when you run `arr()` it doesn't know what n is

you have to put something inside the brackets `()`

if you want the program not to break when you call it without putting anything in it, you can use `try` and `except`

```py
try:
    arr()
except:
    print("error!")
```

Comment: Sure, but I'm doing this on a website and it calls arr(), I'm not allowed to touch it. I only write the arr(n) function.

Comment: @winston What do you want it to return when you call `arr()` ?